# Countdown label on asp.net redirect page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, redirect

After a user clicks the log out button I have it take them to a redirection page which displays a message and says " Logging out and Redirecting in *?* seconds." I am using

```
Response.AddHeader("REFRESH", "3;URL=Login.aspx");
```

is there a way to display how many seconds are left until they are redirected in label?

Comment: When the logout button is clicked, you could simply start a timed event in javascript, decrementing some variable and displaying it wherever you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

In your redirect page you need to use JavaScript to handle it.

This sample may help you: http://javascriptsource.com/navigation/countdown-redirect.html

Answer (score 1):

Following up on my comment, you could accomplish your solution via the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var timeLeft = 3;
    function decrementCounter() {
        if (timeLeft > 0) {
            document.all('countDown').innerHTML = "Redirecting in " + timeLeft + "...";
            timeLeft--;
            setTimeout("decrementCounter()", 1000);
        }
        else {
            window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
        }
    }
</script>

<body>
    <form>
    <label id="countDown">3</label>
        <input type="button" value="Display alert box in 3 seconds" onclick="decrementCounter()" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

For example ,

When you Click the Logout button , You can create a count down javascript by dynamic

```
    protected void OnLogout(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = "~/Login.aspx";
        string msg = "Logging out and Redirecting in ? ";
        StringBuilder js = new StringBuilder("<script language=\"javascript\">")
                .Append("var ts = 3; setInterval(\"redirect()\",1000);")
                .Append("function redirect(){  if(ts == 0){")
                .Append("window.location.href=\"" + url + "\"; }else{")
                .Append("document.body.innerHTML = \"msg \" + (ts--)+\"seconds\";}}")
                .Append("</script>");
        Response.Write(js.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a client-side technology, I.e. JavaScript. Using server-side will require calls to the server which is not needed for something simple like this.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using Microsoft `aspx`, you can create a label on the client side and implement an `AJAX` by giving your code-behind the **Id** of the **label** and changing its value base on the time left.